# Jasmine testing mouseover events in d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm looking at producing interactive chart elements using d3.js

I'm trying to test the change in fill colours due to a mouseover event with jasmine. Ideally, I want the colour of the path element to change to '#ff0000' on a mouseover but my jasmine terminal tells me that isn't happening - the element appear to remain the same colour as initially set, for instance my element with id #1 produces: Expected '#1f77b4' to be '#ff0000'.

I'm using the jquery and jasmine-jquery libraries as well.

Relevant code from my donut chart fixture, DonutChartFixture.html

```
var color = d3.scale.category20();

var path = svg.selectAll("path")
              .data(pie(data))
              .enter().append("path").attr("class", "path")
              .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
              // removed id declaration here
              .attr("d", arc)
              .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "#ff0000");})
              .on("mouseout" , function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", function(d) {   
                                                                   return d.color;
                                                                 });});

// want to highlight the first path element
var path_one = d3.select('.path').attr("id", "path_one");
```

And a test from my spec file, DonutChart.js

```
function loadDonutChart() {
    loadFixtures('DonutChartFixture.html');
}

describe("Mouseover events", function() {
    var spyEvent;

    beforeEach(function() {
        loadDonutChart();
    });

    // updated test for element d3.select('.path').attr("id", "path_one")
    it("#path_one should change fill colour to rgb(255,0,0)", function() {
        spyEvent = spyOnEvent('#path_one', 'mouseover');
        $('#path_one').trigger("mouseover");
        // expect('mouseover').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn('#path_one');
        expect(path_one.style('fill')).toEqual('rgb(255,0,0)');
    });

});
```

As you can see, I've tried selecting elements by id as well as by tag name to no avail, both produce the same readout as given above. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've come up with a passing testing, largely inspired by the answer provided here, [Testing Mouseover event in D3 with Sinon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057738/testing-mouseover-event-in-d3-with-sinon/24068018#24068018). The only real difference is using d3/jasmine syntax in place of Sinon. The following passes correctly:

```
it("#path_one should change fill colour to rgb(255,0,0)", function() {
    var oldColor = path.style('fill');
    document.getElementById('path_one').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover'));
    expect(d3.select('#path_one').style('fill')).not.toEqual(oldColor);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code you are setting the style, and in the test, you are setting the attribute. Trying changing to one or the other for both. In addition, the browser will mostly likely coerce the hex color string into a rgb color string. Therefore, if you set the color to '#ff0000', it will likely be coerced into 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'. Finally, jQuery's `trigger` won't fire event's registered with d3's `on`. See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/100 for details.

Comment: I've made the change suggested, but it doesn't seem to get me the correct answer. 

The test using $('path') now gives:
    Expected 'rgb(31, 119, 180)' to equal '#ff0000'

The test using $('#1') now gives:
    TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: I just noticed that you are setting the attribute fill right after the enter. Is that consistent with your mouseover and test now as well?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. I can see you're referring the sixth line of DonutChartFixture.html but not sure how that relates to the test. The code is as is given.

Comment: Because you are first setting the **attribute** `fill`, then when you mouseover, you are setting it via css using **style**. Then you are testing that **atttribue** `fill` is then equal to what you set via **style**. This isn't going to pass. In addition, d3 will coerce hex color strings into rgb strings so you have to write your test to check for the rgb string of the color. Checkout this: http://plnkr.co/edit/XX1VGNBqcnE7haocUxEB?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your example. I made the advised changes and I have made a few changes to make sure I'm selecting the correct element: I've labelled the first path element d3.select('.path') returns by default with the id '#path_one' so I can correct select that element by id. However, although I getting a test like expect('mouseover').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn('#path_one') to correctly pass I'm still getting the incorrect colour comparison: Expected 'rgb(31, 119, 180)' to equal 'rgb(255,0,0)'.

Comment: After doing some more testing, and some quick googling, this is because using jQuery's trigger method doesn't fire the event handler in d3. Checkout https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/100 for a solution.

Comment: I'm really unsure of how to proceed. Could you provide a concrete example in the context of the original question? Firing a mouseover event and checking the change in fill colour.