# Testing Mouseover event in D3 with Sinon

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, bdd, sinon

I'm having trouble trying to get my test to pass. I would like to be able to use a spy to check whether or not the mouseover event was correctly called. Currently I am getting the following error, "Error: expected on to have been called at least once but was never called". Part of the confusion on my part relates to the differences between d3 and jQuery selectors, I'm more than happy to use the latter, but I'm not sure how to correctly use the former in a test to get the result I want.

My dependencies are d3, jQuery, mocha, chai, sinon, and sinon-chai.

Relevant code from my index.html file,

```
<script src="fixtures.js"></script>
<div id="mocha"></div>
<script src="mocha.js"></script>
<script src="chai.js"></script>
<script src="sinon-chai.js"></script>
<script src="sinon-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    mocha.ui('bdd');
    mocha.reporter('html');
    var expect = chai.expect;
 </script>
 <script src="tests.js"></script>
 <script>
    mocha.run();
</script>
```

fixtures.js,

```
var path = svg.selectAll("path")
          .data(pie(data))
          .enter().append("path").attr("class", "path")
          .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
          .attr("d", arc)
          .on("mouseover", function() { d3.select(this).style("fill", "#ff0000"); })
          .on("mouseout" , function() { d3.selectAll("path").style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); }); });

//  I wanted to test my understanding of d3 selectors
var path_one = d3.select('.path').attr("id", "path_one");
```

tests.js,

```
describe('Donut Chart', function() {
    describe("Mouseover events", function() {
        it("should call on('mouseover')", function () {
            var spy = sinon.spy(path, "on");
            $('path').mouseenter();
            sinon.assert.called(spy);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have some `<path>` elements in your DOM? What do you get if you call `$('path')` in the JS console?

Comment: Also, what happens if you change the call to be `$('path').mouseover();`? (since your test is talking about mouseover rather than mouseenter)

Comment: The path elements refer to the set of all five of the arc segments of my chart (this is d3 syntax). I was using $('path').mouseenter() as I know that gives me the correct result using pure jQuery i.e. it triggers the event as expected. Doing either $('path').mouseover() or $('path').mouseenter() returns me an array of all five path elements.

Comment: sorry... I meant, in the test, change it to `$('path').mouseover();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a few issues here; we can sort out your syntax, but we also have to sort out the intention.

The error message "Error: expected `on` to have been called at least once but was never called" is accurate. **`on` isn't called during your test**. It's only called in your fixtures, to set up the event handlers. You're also triggering a `mouseenter` event but your listeners are for `mouseover` and `mouseout`. In the real world, you'd get a `mouseover` very soon after a `mouseenter` event, but when you fake it with jQuery that won't happen. jQuery is a non-starter anyway; see below.

---

You could try to fix this by changing them from anonymous functions to something named, like this:

```js
var mouseOverHandler = function() { 
    d3.select(this).style('fill', '#ff0000');
};
```

And then bind it to your `path` with `path.on('mouseover', mouseOverHandler)`. You'd think you can now spy on `mouseOverHandler`, but **that won't work either**. Your function will be bound when you call `on`, so swapping it out for a Sinon spy later won't have any effect.

### jQuery triggering won't work with D3

Another problem is [you can't use jQuery to trigger D3 events because jQuery events aren't DOM events](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/906). So you should replace your call to `$('path').mouseenter()` to something like `document.getElementById('path_one').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover'));` (Noting that this is changing the code from "trigger `mouseenter` on all paths" to "trigger `mouseover` on the element with id `path_one`").

### Testing the wrong thing

You could futz around with refactoring so you *can* swap out your callback with something you can spy, but fundamentally you're testing the wrong thing. Essentially, you're trying to write a test for D3; "When I add an event listener, make sure that event listener gets called." Instead, you should test your actual code's behaviour: "When someone mouses over the chart, its colour should change".

If you *really* want to assert that your event handler was bound, you could do that:

```js
expect(path.on('mouseover')).to.be.a('function')
```

But if you want to make sure your colour is changed, you want your test to be as follows:

```js
describe("Mouseover events", function() {
    it("should update the colours when a user mouses over the paths", function () {
        var oldColor = path.style('fill');
        document.getElementById('path_one').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover'));
        expect(path.style('fill')).to.not.equal(oldColor);
    });
});
```

Comment: That's a really helpful answer, the tests/events pass/fire as expected! Cheers. Do you have any information on the issues you discuss about spies and binding?

Comment: `expect(path.on('mouseover')).to.be.a('function')` would fail on Mocha throwing `TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.`.